# Kubuntu 17.04 - no Internet connection when using APT, can't ping sites by name

Tags: networking, kubuntu, dns

I just installed a Kubuntu image on my Asus EEE Netbook through USB Live (ubuntu 17.04). The installation worked fine, with no errors on drivers installation. Through the graphic interface I was able to connect to my wireless network aquiring a IP address.

But I could not proceed with `apt-get update`, which returns

```
could not resolve the <linux repo link>
```

Pinging `8.8.8.8` works, but other sites are listed as unknown name or service. If I ping the IP address it works. It seems to be something related to DNS config. So I tried editing `/etc/resolv.conf` to contain `nameserver 8.8.8.8` but still no DNS resolution. Cable has the same behavior.

Can anyone give some help here?

Answer (score 0):

My resolv.conf is configured as follows:

```
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search 192.168.178.1 <MyRouterName>
```

The first line is a local address I get if I try the following:

```
$ nslookup google.de
Server:         127.0.1.1
Address:        127.0.1.1#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   google.de
Address: 172.217.18.163
$
```

Maybe it's useful for you.